# How to add only one observation at a time amongst several observations in R?

Tags: r, loops, repeat, rbind

Say I have observations for several periods for financial data, how can I create a function in R that only adds one observation at a time throughout my dataset so that I can compare how a single observation impacts my original data? 
Say for instance that I have something like this:

```
             Apple Microsoft     Tesla    Amazon
     2010 0.8533719 0.8078440 0.2620114 0.1869552
     2011 0.7462573 0.5127501 0.5452448 0.1369686
     2012 0.7580671 0.5062639 0.7847919 0.8362821
     2013 0.3154078 0.6960258 0.7303597 0.6057027
     2014 0.4741735 0.3906580 0.4515726 0.1396147
     2015 0.4230036 0.4728911 0.1262413 0.7495193
     2016 0.2396552 0.5001825 0.6732861 0.8535837
     2017 0.2007575 0.8875209 0.5086837 0.2211072
#And I define my original covariance matrix as follows: 
     cov.m <- cov(x[1:5,])
#I would like to add only one new observation at a time, so the results should be:
     cov(x[1:5,]), cov(x[1:6,]), cov(x[1:7,]), cov(x[1:8,])
```

I have tried using rbind and a repeat loop, but it seems like I still have to define every row to include in rbind, which is quite tedious if I want to test on say 100+ different observations as I then manually need to specify all the observations, and I would have no use for the repeat loop in that case either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you closer to your expected output?

```
lapply(5:nrow(x), function(y) cov(x[1:y, ]))
```